# If condition not working in model of codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to implement a "like" button for my website. I am using Codigniter, Ajax and Jquery. When the like button is clicked data should be entered to database and if unlike button is pressed data should delete from database. But I am facing a problem in model, data is not added to database when I click like button. Please help me to find a solution.

This is my Jquery file "likeitem.js"

```js
function likeItem(postId)
{
    if ($("#likeItem_"+postId).text() == "Like") 
    {
        $("#likeItem_"+postId).html('Unlike');
        var purpose = "Like";
    }
    else 
    {
        $("#likeItem_"+postId).html('Like');
        var purpose = "UnLike";
    }
    $.ajax({
                type    : "POST",
                url     : "http://localhost/codeig_smarty/index.php/user/likeItem",
                data    : "postId=" + postId + "purpose=" + purpose,
                success : function() 
                {
                   
                }
            });
    return false;
}
```

This is my model "usermodel.php"

```html
    public function itemLike()
    {
        $id         = $this->session->userdata('userID');
        $postId     = $this->input->post('postId');
        $purpose    = $this->input->post('purpose');
        
        if($purpose=="Like")
        {
//            echo 'test';
//            exit();
        $data   = array(
                        "userID"        => $id,
                        "postTextID"    => $postId,
                        );
        $this->db->insert('like', $data);    
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'hai';
        }
    }
```

This is my view file "home.tpl"

```html
 <li><a class="like-unlike" href="#" id="likeItem_{$item['postID']}" onclick="likeItem({$item['postID']})">Like</a></li>
```

This is my Controller "user.php"

```html
 public function likeItem()
    {
        $this->usermodel->itemLike();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistake here. You forgot to put `&` symbol. Try this code.

```
data    : "postId=" + postId + "&purpose=" + purpose,
```

Full code:
If you want to manipulate result returned from ajax, you can do something on success block as following code :

```
   $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "http://localhost/codeig_smarty/index.php/user/likeItem",
            data    : "postId=" + postId + "&purpose=" + purpose,
            success : function(data) 
            {
               // do seomthing here with data
               // console.log(data) --> to see data return or not
            }
        });
```

Comment: @codebugger Glad it worked out. Accept my answer, so other people who have same problem in future can refer later on.